# How to get a process instance (with pid or listening port) in Python?

Tags: python, process, port, pid

In Python, `subprocess.Popen(cmd)` can return a `subprocess.Popen` instance, which represents a process with certain `cmd`. I'm wondering, is it possible to get such an instance by the port that the process listens to, or by the pid of the process?

For example, is there an API such as `subprocess.getProcessesByPort(port)` or `subprocess.getProcess(pid)`?

I understand such flexibility might cause security problems and will not be surprised if this is impossible. I didn't use this module before and want to look for more insights for it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[psutil package](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) might provide what you want in a cross-platform manner.

Comment: Thank you! I checked this module just now and it's indeed able to retrieve a process by its pid. So is it possible to cast the instance into the ones in `subprocess` module?

Comment: I don't this so. Because Popen's  constructor invokes **a new** process: On POSIX, the class uses os.execvp()-like behavior to execute the child program. On Windows, the class uses the Windows CreateProcess() function. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). On the other hand psutil has it's own class for the process abstraction: `psutil.Process` which might provide functionality you needed from `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: Got it that makes lots of sense. Thank you so much!